# Valgrind - snprintf : Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c, printf, valgrind

After launching a program thru valgrind I got the following message :

```
==9290== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==9290==    at 0x4E82A03: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1661)
==9290==    by 0x4EA9578: vsnprintf (vsnprintf.c:119)
==9290==    by 0x4E8B531: snprintf (snprintf.c:33)
==9290==    by 0x400820: _function (in /home/snp/prog/TEST)
==9290==    by 0x4006D5: start (in /home/snp/prog/TEST)
==9290==    by 0x40085C: main (in /home/snp/prog/TEST)
==9290==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==9290==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9290==    by 0x400715: init (in /home/snp/prog/TEST)
==9290==    by 0x400857: main (in /home/snp/prog/TEST)
```

The following code reproduce the error :

```
#include <net/if.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>

#define TARGET "8.8.8.8"
#define DEVICE "eth0"

static int _function(void);

struct remote
{
    char *target;
    char device[IFNAMSIZ];
};

struct remote * st_args;

int start(void)
{
    return (_function());
}

int init(void)
{
    st_args = malloc (sizeof (struct remote));
    if (st_args == NULL)
        return (-1);

    st_args->target = malloc (sizeof (TARGET)+1);
    if (st_args->target == NULL) 
    {
        free (st_args);
        return (-1);
    }

    strncpy(st_args->target, TARGET , sizeof(TARGET)-1);
    strncpy(st_args->device, DEVICE, IFNAMSIZ-1);

   return 0;
}

void stop(void)
{
    if (st_args != NULL) 
    {
        free (st_args->target);
        free (st_args);
    }
}

static int _function(void)
{
    char cmd[256];

    memset(cmd, 0, sizeof(cmd));

    snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "ping -I %s %s", st_args->device, st_args->target);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    init();
    start();
    stop(); 
   return 0;
}
```

I still does not understand the issue, why valgrind does not accept the `snprintf` command. In addition, the array contains the expected string after the line execution.

Comment: I suppose valgrind does not know about the state of `st_args`? Maybe try using a local `st_args`.

Comment: `strncpy(st_args->target, TARGET , sizeof(TARGET)-1);` bad habits. (malloc does **not** initialise the memory to all zeros!) ... and similar for `IFNAMSIZ-1`

Comment: It's kind of puzzling you're using the right tool for the job (`snprintf`), and the wrong tool for any job (`strncpy`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valgrind's message,

> ==9290== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

is reasonably self-explanatory: the program is observed to be relying on on uninitialized memory to make a decision.  Happening in a standard library function as it does as it does, it is natural to suppose that there is something wrong with the function arguments.  Since you're specifically printing strings, the most likely cause is that one of the string arguments is unterminated.

And indeed, at least one is.  Consider this code:

> ```
> #define TARGET "8.8.8.8"
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> strncpy(st_args->target, TARGET , sizeof(TARGET)-1);
> ```

In trying to be safe, you have shot yourself in the foot.  `strncpy()` copies at most the specified number of bytes, but it *does not* append a terminator afterwards.  Thus, its Linux manual page contains this warning:

> **Warning**: If there is no null byte among the first `n` bytes of `src`, the string placed in `dest` will  not be null terminated.

You have *ensured* that the situation described in that warning takes place -- no null terminator is written, and the last byte allocated for `st_args->target` remains uninitialized.

Since you are careful to allocate enough space for the full string to begin with, including the terminator, the `strncpy()` is overkill anyway.  Just use `strcpy()`.  Or indeed, if your system has `strdup()` or you're willing to write an implementation, then `strdup()` is much cleaner than `malloc()` + `strcpy()`.

Alternatively, if you want to use `strncpy()` then it's a good idea to ensure that the destination string is terminated by following up each `strncpy()` call by manually writing a terminator to the last byte of the destination.  In this case, that would be

```
st_args->target[sizeof(TARGET)] = '\0';
```

Note also that you actually allocate one more byte than you need, for the `sizeof` a string literal includes the terminator.  The code just above is written for that actual one-byte-too-many allocation.

Comment: thank for your explanation ! Last remaining question, you said `strdup()` is more safe and cleaner. I gonna to use `strdup()` instead of `strncpy()` in order to store the target's address but I still have to use `strncpy()` for the device's name because there is no better way, isn't ?

Comment: @SnP, yes, you cannot use `strdup()` when the desired destination is an array.  Therefore, for the `st_args->device` case, I recommend either using `strncpy()` and afterward forcing string termination as I already described, or else verifying the source string length first, and using regular `strcpy()` if it's ok.