# Why is valgrind reporting an uninitialised value error?

Tags: c, valgrind

When I run the following code with

```
valgrind ./test
```

I get the following error:

```
==8389== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==8389==    at 0x4E88CC0: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1632)
==8389==    by 0x4E8F898: printf (printf.c:33)
==8389==    by 0x40072F: main (test.c:30)
```

I have added a comment to the line it is complaining about below:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  char str[] = "a string";

  int str_len = strlen(str);
  char *str2 = malloc(sizeof(char) * (str_len+1)); //source of uninitialised value
  strncpy(str2, str, str_len);

  printf("%s",str2); //source of error

  free(str2);
  exit (0);
}
```

str2 is assigned a value by strncpy so why would it be uninitialised by the time it gets to printf?

Comment: OT:  regarding: `char *str2 = malloc(sizeof(char) * (str_len+1));`  The expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1,  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and just clutter the code,  Suggest removing that expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code never initializes `str2[str_len]`.

In your code, `str_len` is 8. You need `strncpy` to copy 9 bytes, the 8 bytes of "a string" and the zero byte that terminates the string. But you only let `strncpy` copy `str_len` bytes, that is, 8. So you do not copy the terminating zero byte and `printf` reads off the end of the data you copied looking for it.

So you have a bug. Instead, pass `strncpy` the size of the buffer or one more than the `strlen(str)`.

Comment: I just this moment realised that strncpy doesn't add a null terminator, thanks to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423114/valgrind-snprintf-conditional-jump-or-move-depends-on-uninitialised-values

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. corrects several logic errors in the posted code
2. added missing '#include' statements for needed header files
3. performs the desired functionality
4. includes the terminator NUL byte in the call to `strncpy()` so call to `printf()` works correctly
5. cleanly compiles
6. uses proper signature for `main()` when parameters are not going to be used
7. added error checking and handling after call to `malloc()`

And now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void )   // <-- changed
{
    char str[] = "a string";

    size_t str_len = strlen(str);
    char *str2 = malloc( str_len+1 ); 
    if( !str2 )  // <-- added error checking
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc succesful

    strncpy(str2, str, str_len+1);  // <-- changed 

    printf("%s",str2); 

    free(str2);
    // removed 'exit()' statement
}
```

and here is the output from a run of the proposed code:

```
a string
```